# html5 validation error on simple javascript dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a simple javascript dropdown menu that I’m getting an HTML5 validation error. The error is “Bad value goto(this); for attribute onchange on element select: identifier is a reserved word.” Can anyone help me out with what to change in the code:

```
<script>
<!--
function goto(choose){
var selected=choose.options[choose.selectedIndex].value;
    if(selected != ""){
    location.href=selected;
    }
}
//-->
</script>
<strong><SELECT onChange="goto(this);"></strong>
<option value="">--Choose studio--</option>
<option value="[home]/studio-1/">Studio 1</option>
<option value="[home]/studio-2">Studio 2</option>
</SELECT>';
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your error. See this ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/ApbhY/)***

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you mind taking a look here: http://www.audarya.org/kurssit/alkeiskurssit/

Comment: Never mind...got it worked out now by changing the function name.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, `goto` is a reserved word in Javascript, even though it's not implemented.

You should change the function name you're using - `function gotoSomewhere()`, perhaps.

Comment: @user2740305 Change the function name you're using: `function goSomewhere()` perhaps.

Comment: @user2740305 - If this answer solved your issue, can you please select the green checkmark to help future visitors troubleshoot by indicating this worked for you?

Comment: @MikeW - Perhaps you can edit your suggestion from your comment into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
<!--
function goThere(choose){
var selected=choose.options[choose.selectedIndex].value;
    if(selected != ""){
    location.href=selected;
    }
}
//-->
</script>
<strong><SELECT onChange="goThere(this);"></strong>
<option value="">--Choose studio--</option>
<option value="[home]/studio-1/">Studio 1</option>
<option value="[home]/studio-2">Studio 2</option>
</SELECT>';
```

goto is a reserved word in Javascript, use a different name instead as in the example above.